# Counting number on the seven segment with AVR

Tags: c, interrupt, avr, seven-segment-display, proteus

I have written a program for my At-mega 32 in order to increase and decrease numbers from 0 to 9 and reverse (9 to 0) with the two tactile switch witch you can see in the picture.

But the problem is that while all of the numbers are demonstrated by pressing those switches, only numbers 4 and 7 don't appear properly !?.

My seven segments instead of number 4 demonstrates what you can see in the first picture and for number 7 is shows what you can see in the second picture.

I would appreciate it if someone could have a look at my codes and schematic which I have shared here and help me to find the issue.

Thank you so much,

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include "global.h"
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

uint8_t Codes[] = {0xFC, 0x60, 0xDA, 0xF2, 0x66, 0xB6, 0xBE, 0xE0, 0xFE, 0xF6};

uint8_t count=0;
//temp=0

void display(uint8_t digit);
void config(void);

ISR(INT0_vect)
{
  if(count<9)
  {
    count++;
    display(count);
  } 
}

ISR(INT1_vect)
{
  if(count>0)
  {
    count--;
    display(count);
  } 
}

int main(void)
{
  config();

  while(1)
  {    
  }
}

void config(void)
{
  DDRA=0xFF;
  PORTA=0;
  cbi(DDRD,2);
  cbi(DDRD,3);
  sbi(PORTD,2);
  sbi(PORTD,3);

  GICR=(1<<INT1) | (1<<INT0);
  MCUCR=0; //low level sensitivity
  GIFR=(1 << INTF1) | (INTF0);
  sei();
}

void display(uint8_t digit)
{
  PORTA=Codes[digit];}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check that all the segments of the display are connected to their correct port pin. It seems as if your display is bottom-up, segment "a" should be connected to PA7. -- The other numbers might seem correct just by accident.

Comment: I checked the connection and they match with my program codes. I feel there are some problems in my codes which are causing the issue.

Comment: Your code looks correct, I even checked the patterns of `Codes[]`. Segment "a" is PA7, "b" is PA6, and so on until "g" is PA1. Unfortunately the display part does not show the pin names.

Comment: You can check the correct wiring if you change `Codes[]` to `{0x80, 0x40, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02, 0, 0, 0 }` and see if each count lights up just one segment. The sequence should be "a", "b", and so on to "g". The last three zeroes are just to make the array big enough. Compare the segments with [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display#Characters).

Comment: you write my seven segment connection was wrong, I didn't change the code but by fixing the connection between the seven segment and micro possessor everything now are working properly, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Great that we solved your issue. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and I suggest to mark my answer.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct, I even checked the patterns of `Codes[]`.

Each bit of the patterns is assigned to one specific segment of the display:

| Port bit | Segment |
| --- | --- |
| PA7 | a |
| PA6 | b |
| PA5 | c |
| PA4 | d |
| PA3 | e |
| PA2 | f |
| PA1 | g |

Your wiring is wrong, unfortunately the schematic does not show the pin names of the display. It seems as if it's upside down.